# Creating a monad for incrementally storing results type not matching

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to get a better understanding of monads by trying to create one.  The idea is to create a monad that just stores all results.  However, I just can't get the type to match up.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let 
        v1 = return (1,1)
        v2 = return (8,8)
        x = move v1 v2
    print x


newtype Accum a = Accum { open :: (a, [a]) }
  deriving (Show)

instance Monad Accum where
    return v = Accum (v, [v])
    (>>=) m f = let (r1, l1) = open m
                    r2       = f r1
                    (r3, l3) = open r2
                in Accum (r3, l1 ++ l3)

move :: Accum (Int,Int) -> Accum (Int,Int) -> Accum (Int,Int)
move p1 p2 = do
    (x1,y1) <- p1
    (x2,y2) <- p2
    return (x1+x2, y1+y2)
```

In line `Accum (r3, l1 ++ l3)`, `l1` is of the type `a` where as `l3` is always type `b`.  How can I let the side effect of accumulating the results be done for me by the monad?

Comment: I believe such an instance would violate the monad laws, e.g. `return x >>= return` wouldn't be equivalent to `return x`.

Comment: Are you sure what you want is not the [Writer monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/docs/Control-Monad-Writer.html)?

Comment: It might be but I just want a simple water down version just to see how it all connects together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very similar to the `Writer [a]` monad, and I don't think there is a simpler way of fixing it than closing the gap in all but naming. Specifically:

Since a monad must allow an arbitrary result type, the type of the effect part cannot depend on the type of the result part, so change the type definition to

```
newtype Accum a b = Accum { open :: (b, [a]) }
```

To fulfil the monad laws, `return` must not have a nontrivial effect, so change the definition of that to

```
return v = Accum (v, [])
```

Now you need to have an explicit action to store with, aka `tell` from `MonadWriter`:

```
tell as = Accum ((), as)
```

Finally, change the type signatures to include the extra type argument as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I read your request as

> Create a Monad that records all intermediate results.

Such a thing cannot exist in haskell. First of all, a monad must be a functor. I assume you already know what that is.

I see only two implementations for `fmap` that roughly keep the "record computation" semantic and pass type checking:

```
fmap f (Accum (x,xs)) = Accum (f x, map f xs) -- map history
fmap f (Accum (x,xs)) = Accum (f x,[]) -- forget history
```

The first one makes your `Accum a` identical to a non-empty list `[a]`, lists are well known to be monad instances; not quite what you want.
The second is even duller.

As you turn from functors to monads with bind (`>>=`), things do not get better.

As Ørjan Johansen already stated, the `a` in `m a` can be of *any* type. As you want to get a better understanding of monads, how about this: In `m a` let the `a` be `m a` itself. Now you have `m (m a)`. And for every monad, there is a method

```
join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

that removes one level of nesting. A list of lists can be turned into a list, a tree of trees into a tree, and an IO-Action, that yields an IO-Action can be turned into a single action by just executing one after the other.

I must resist the urge to write another crappy monad tutorial...